# Traefik: Cannot start service: OCI runtime create failed: sysctl "kernel.domainname" is not in a separate kernel namespace: unknown

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

Tried [raising this on GitHub](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4311) but the Traefik bot doesn't think it is a bug:

#### What did you do?

Attempted to pull latest Docker image from DockerHub via Docker Compose and bring up the container

Ubuntu 18.04.1 (Kernel 4.15.0-42-generic)

#### What did you expect to see?

Successful start of Traefik container

#### What did you see instead?

Failed to start Traefik container

> ERROR: for traefik  Cannot start service traefik: OCI runtime create failed: sysctl "kernel.domainname" is not in a separate kernel namespace: unknown

#### Output of `traefik version`: (*What version of Traefik are you using?*)

`Version:      v1.7.6
Codename:     maroilles
Go version:   go1.11.3
Built:        2018-12-14_06:43:37AM
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`

#### If applicable, please paste the log output in DEBUG level (`--logLevel=DEBUG` switch)

`time="2018-12-16T08:44:09Z" level=error msg="vulcand/oxy/forward/websocket: Error when copying from backend to client: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF"
time="2018-12-16T09:06:09Z" level=error msg="vulcand/oxy/forward/websocket: Error when copying from backend to client: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF"
time="2018-12-16T09:28:00Z" level=error msg="vulcand/oxy/forward/websocket: Error when copying from backend to client: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF"
time="2018-12-17T11:56:28Z" level=error msg="vulcand/oxy/forward/websocket: Error when copying from client to backend: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF"`

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the latest version of Traefik has deprecated the `domainname` parameter.

Removing this setting from Docker Compose allowed me to pull the latest image and bring up the container.